# What is the package name for DCUO

Tags: raspbian

I am new to raspberry pi and I was wondering what the package name for DC Universe Online is.

Comment: If your expecting to be able to run x86 applications you can think again. The Pi is built on the ARM architecture, so any Windows programs are not going to work on it. Unless someone has developed a version of the program to run on the Pi, like Minecraft Pi edition for example, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Universe_Online) page there is no Linux version, so there is no package available. I did a quick web search and saw that some people were playing the game using wine or crossover. However, I doubt the Pi has enough memory or CPU to make the game playable on the Pi.

Comment: The minimum requirements are available [here](https://help.daybreakgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/230625527-What-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-to-run-DC-Universe-Online-). Looks like PC/Windows only, 3GHz P4 CPU, 1GB RAM, plus a dedicated graphics chipset, all of which would likely be bumped upwards if you were using wine, crossover, or something else to make it run on Mac or Linux. *Definitely* a non-starter.